# Leer puerto serial de Arduino con un Script Python

Tags: python, arduino

Estoy tratando de leer el puerto serial de arduino con un script de python, el tema es que tengo dos sensores (HCSR-04 y LM35) y un módulo HC-05 (bluetooth) el cual transmite los valores de los sensores (por el lado de arduino todo bien, imprime los valores en el monitor serial), el tema se me complica con el script de python, en un principio recibo los valores en formato byte que se almacenaban en una variable y los podía ver por la consola de python al imprimir dicha variable "print(datos)", pero a la hora de tratar de recuperar los datos individualmente para poder procesarlos surge el problema, trate de utilizar un "print(datos[0])" y en vez de mostrarme el primer valor que es 27 me muestra un 50 que es el equivalente a 2 en ASCII y si hago un "print(datos[1])" me muestra el valor 55 que es el equivalente a 7 en ASCII, entonces se me ocurrió recorrer la lista con un bucle "for" y tratando de identificar el separador (,) y el salto linea, ir armando los valores, pero estoy muy complicado con el tema, sin dejar de mencionar que recién estoy aprendiendo python, entonces recurro a ustedes para que me ayuden a resolver mi pequeño problema, adjunto código Arduino, código Python y error Python

**Código Arduino**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>         //Librería SoftwareSerial
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(10, 11);   //Pines RX|TX Arduino a BT

//Inicio de constantes y variables
const int trig = 2;
const int echo = 3;
int duracion;
int distancia;
int temperatura;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);       //Inicio puerto serial
  bluetooth.begin(57600);    //Inicio módulo bluetooth
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);  //Inicio Pin Trigger en Low
}

void loop() {

  //Solicito valores a las funciones
  int val_0 = mideDistancia();
  int val_1 = mideTemperatura();

  //Envía valores al monitor serial (SI LOS MUESTRA)
  Serial.print(val_0);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(val_1);
  Serial.print("\n");

  //Envía valores vía HC-05
  //bluetooth.println(val_0 + "," + val_1);
  //bluetooth.print("\n");
  delay(1000);
}

//Función mide distancia (HCSR-04)
int mideDistancia(){
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  duracion = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
  distancia = duracion / 58.2;
  return distancia;
}

//Función mide temperatura (LM35)
int mideTemperatura(){
  int suma = 0;
  int lm35 = analogRead(A0);  //Lectura del Pin Analógico A0
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    temperatura = ((lm35 * 5000.0 / 1023) / 10);
    suma = temperatura + suma;
    delay(200);
  }
  temperatura = suma / 5;   //Promedio de 5 Lecturas
  return temperatura;
}
```

**Código Python**

```
import serial, time
puertoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(2)   #Espera 2 segundos para conectar puerto serial

while 1:
    try:

        datos = puertoSerial.readline()

        valor = 0       #Valor caracter ASCII
        cadena = ""     #Valor compuesto por caracteres ASCII
        incremento = 0  #Variable contador

        while incremento <= max(datos):

            valor = str(datos[incremento])

            if valor != "44" or valor != "10":   #Si es coma o salto de linea
                cadena = cadena + valor

            else:
                print(cadena)
                valor = 0

            incremento += 1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

puertoSerial.close()
```

**Error Python**

```
>>> %Run pythonLecturaHC05_3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/proyectoSensores/pythonLecturaHC05_3.py", line 16, in <module>
    valor = str(datos[incremento])
IndexError: index out of range
```

---

Si, si totalmente de acuerdo, yo me equivoque al subir el programa ese fue una de las primera pruebas que hice, partiendo de este programa original

**Programa Phyton:**

```html
import serial, time
puertoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(2)   #Espera 2 segundos para conectarse al puerto serial

while 1:
    try:
        datos = puertoSerial.readline()
        print(datos)
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

puertoSerial.close()
```

**Respuesta de Programa**

```html
>>> %Run pythonLecturaHC05_2.py
b'27,23\n'
b'27,24\n'
b'27,21\n'
b'27,21\n'
```

Como se puede apreciar, el programa recupera los datos en una variable "datos" valga la redundancia, el tema es que no me sirve este tipo de dato por que es de tipo byte, de alguna manera debo desglosar esa información y recuperar los datos pero que sean de tipo entero o string no me importa, ya de esa manera son más manejables.
Si yo a esta variable "datos le doy un "print(datos[0])" me devuelve un 50 en vez 27, por que en realidad me esta devolviendo el 2 en ASCII y si le hago un "print(datos[1])" me devuelve un 55 que vendría a ser el 7, entonces debo recorrer la variable "datos" e ir transformando los valores en string y concatenandolos, una vez que tenga los valores armados pasarlos por último a decimal, es una embolia, estoy tratando de hacerlo con un blucle for.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás confundiendo funciones.

`max(datos)` te sacará el valor máximo dentro del objeto datos, no la longitud. para eso debes usar `len(datos)`, y sustituir `<=` por `<`

Por ejemplo, si tu lista es [1, 10, 2], `max(datos)` es 10, por lo que el while subirá hasta buscar el índice `datos[10]`, que no existe (solo hay 0, 1 y 2; para los 3 números). En cambio, si usas `len(datos)`, obtienes "3", por lo que `incremento`, si es menor que 3, solo irá del 0 al 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví:

```
import serial, time
puertoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(2)   #Espera 2 segundos para conectar puerto serial

while 1:
    try:

        datosASCII = puertoSerial.readline() #Devuelve b

        print("Lista Inicial", datosASCII)

        datosCaracter = ""
        for valor in datosASCII:
            datosCaracter = datosCaracter + chr(valor)

        print("Lista Resultante", str(datosCaracter))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

puertoSerial.close()
```

**Resultado:**

```
>> %Run pythonLecturaHC05_3.py
Lista Inicial b'27,23\n'
Lista Resultante 27,23

Lista Inicial b'27,21\n'
Lista Resultante 27,21
```

Comment: No solo coloques código sino explica tu solución.

Comment: La intención de la publicación fue solicitar ayuda a la comunidad para resolver ciertos problemas con la ejecución de mi código, pero gracias por tu observación, la voy a tomar en cuenta para futuras publicaciones. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, habiendo superado las primeras líneas de mi código las cuales me complicaron un poco la existencia puedo presentarles el producto final.
Este escript nos permite leer dos sensores (HC-SR04 y LM35) de arduino conectado a una Raspberry Pi vía serial. La lectura de los valores la realizo con este script en Python el cual después de leer los datos los almacena en una base de datos (MySQL - mariaDB) para su posterior procesamiento, del mismo modo que el pan van con la mantequilla, les adjunto el código arduino el cual se encarga de leer los sensores y enviarlos al puerto serial.

**Código Python**

```html
#importando librerías
import mysql.connector, serial, time

#Conectando con la base de datos y creando cursor
conexion = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost"
                                   , user = "miUsuario"
                                   , passwd = "miPassword"
                                   , database = "sensores")
cursor = conexion.cursor()

#Definiendo Query para escritura de valores en tabla
registro = "INSERT INTO datos (distancia, temperatura) values (%s, %s)"


#Conectando con puerto serial de Arduino
puertoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(2)   #Espera 2 segundos para conectar puerto serial

while 1:
    try:
        
        #Lee y almacena los datos de Arduino (cadena ASCII)
        recive_datos = puertoSerial.readline()
        
        #Convertimos caracteres ASCII a String
        convierte_datos = ""
        for valor in recive_datos:
            convierte_datos = convierte_datos + chr(valor)
        
        #Agrupamos caracteres identificando separador
        separador = ","
        nueva_lista = convierte_datos.split(separador)        
        valores = (nueva_lista[0], nueva_lista[1])
        
        #Ejecutando comandos para escritura en la tabla
        cursor.execute(registro, valores)
        #Realizamos los cambios en la tabla
        conexion.commit()
        
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Registro Insertado...")
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

#Cerrando puerto serial y BBDD
puertoSerial.close()
conexion.close()
```

**Código Arduino**

```html
//Librería SoftwareSerial
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Inicio de constantes y variables
#define trig 2
#define echo 3
#define rxpin 10
#define txpin 11
int duracion;
int distancia;
int temperatura;

//Pines (10|11 - Arduino) a (RX|TX - moduloHC05)
SoftwareSerial moduloHC05(rxpin, txpin);

void setup() {
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);  //Inicio Pin Trigger en Low
  Serial.begin(9600);       //Inicio puerto serial
  moduloHC05.begin(38400);  //Inicio módulo bluetooth
}

void loop() {
  
  //Solicitud de valores a las funciones
  int val_0 = mideDistancia();
  int val_1 = mideTemperatura();

  //Imprimimos valores en puerto Serial
  Serial.print(val_0);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(val_1);
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(1000);
}

//Función mide distancia (HCSR-04)
int mideDistancia(){
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  duracion = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
  distancia = duracion / 58.2;
  return distancia;
}

//Función mide temperatura (LM35)
int mideTemperatura(){
  int suma = 0;
  //Lectura del Pin Analógico A0
  int lm35 = analogRead(A0);
  //Se realizan 5 lecturas de Temperatura
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    temperatura = ((lm35 * 5000.0 / 1023) / 10);
    suma = temperatura + suma;
    delay(200);
  }
  //Promedio de las 5 lecturas
  temperatura = suma / 5;
  return temperatura;
}
```

La línea "moduloHC05.begin(38400);  //Inicio módulo bluetooth" del "void setup()" no la tomen en cuenta, estoy tratando hacer otro sketch que se conecte vía bluetooth en vez de puerto serial.
Espero les sirva este aporte, por mi parte doy por cerrado esta publicación.
Saludos